# Why is my CSS not working on my locally-hosted web application?

Tags: css

This is the header partial (EJS template) including the css file link.

There are no errors in chrome developer tools, the other partials and the bootstrap within this are working fine. I have checked for case-sensitivity and file paths. I have no idea why this is not working. Please have a look at the css below and suggest anything that could help me sort it.  The css is not showing but the BS file is. All the other files (with the exception of some logic errors are working. No console errors.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>To-do List</title>
<!--link local and BS5 css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/styles.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>`
```

Comment: Most likely because `/public/styles.css` doesn't point at your CSS. Start by testing what it actually returns using the Network tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Also, as a rule of thumb, you will generally want to apply CSS you've written **after** third-party CSS, not the other way around.

Comment: Based on my Network tab, nothing is returned. The folder for this project contains a 'public' folder with 'styles.css' file inside it.

Comment: What does ‘Nothing’ mean? An HTTP 204 No Content status?

Comment: it didn't say anything but i have resolved it. SOLUTION: when including the 'header.ejs' file as a partial, ensure the syntax is correct <%- (include 'header'); -%>